# ACPI Errors - Ubuntu 16.04/17.04 can not be installed

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, acpi

I have a problem with installing Ubuntu on my desktop computer.
I had Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 dual boot. After one update of Windows, the Ubuntu installation disappeared. 
I tried to install it again with Ubuntu Live USB but when I clicked on 'Install Ubuntu' or 'Try Ubuntu without installing' I got the following errors:

```
  [ 0.016192] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.XHC_.RHUB.HS11] Namespace lookup 
  failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/dswload-210)
  [ 0.016195] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog 
    (20150930/psobject-227)
  [ 0.016222] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, (SSDT:xh_rvp08) while loading 
  table (20150930/tbxfload-193)
  [ 0.021348] ACPI Error: 1 table load failures, 7 successful 
  (20150930/tbxfload-214)
```

This text is repeated on the whole screen and after the first time it seems blurry as if there are video card issues. 
The same Ubuntu Live USB works fine on another PC.
 I tried also with Ubuntu 17.04 - still the same errors.
I deleted Windows installation as well and tried to install Ubuntu again.
 Without success.
Then I tried Windows installation and it installed correct. 
After a lot of researching in the web, I reached to the conclusion that I have to turn off ACPI in order to install Ubuntu. So I did it. It got installed but it behaved strange, the resolution could not be changed and it started to restarts repeatedly. So I deleted the installation again, considering turning ACPI off was not a good solution.
Has anyone ever had the same or similar problem? What are these errors displaying? How to fix them?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nobody has no idea about it obvioulsy :D

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: No. I just gave up.

Answer (score 3):

On my DELL XPS 9560 I had to:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Then add `acpi_rev_override=5` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_rev_override=5"
```

Run `sudo update-grub`.

Profit (hopefully it will work when you reboot, and rev override is better than turning off ACPI completely. Also I recommend you to update Kernel at least to 4.14.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try it soon and will write what happened.

Comment: Can you do this on Live USB? I am having a trouble while I try to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes you can. You have to press ctrl+shift or something, or ctrl+shift+e or only e when you have selected boot entry and want to edit it in Grub (boot manager for Live CD).

Comment: Don't work for me on Dell Inspiron 15 5xxx

Comment: this is more relevant I think : https://askubuntu.com/a/993734/307184 and this one : https://askubuntu.com/a/962099/307184

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is exactly the same problem you had, but a few days back, after a windows update my Linux Mint stopped working, with ACPI AE_NOT_FOUND errors. Turns out, the reason was that it tried to mount NTFS drives on boot, and the **windows update switched "fast boot" back on**, which makes the windows boot time faster, but also causes an inconsistent state on NTFS partitions (among other things as I understand, this was just my case), rendering them inaccessible to any other operating system, as the "missing parts" from the consistent state of the partition are stored in a data structure internal to, and only readable by windows.

As this question is almost a year old, this might not be useful info to you, but your question is on the first page when researching similar problems, so it might help a few people out.

[The procedure to turn off fast boot in windows.](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html#option1)