# Install Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell 15 7567

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, system-installation, dell, secure-boot

I just bought a Dell Inspiron 7567 and I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04, 17.04, ...

I can see the grub menu, where I can select the options, but sometimes it crushes even before Ubuntu Live loads, others once it's loaded, and I cannot run any program and I just can reboot and start over again.

I've disabled secure boot, added nomodeset in the boot options, ... but nothing works.

I don't think the problem is about the bootable USB, as I used several of them and I have the issue with all of them.

A bit more of info. The computer comes with windows 10 installed in a m.2 ssd. I bought a ssd drive where I plan to install Linux

It's getting kind of frustrating/disappointing, I start thinking that I will have to stay with Windows until there is a new linux version that does not have all this problems

Has anyone succeeded in installing Ubuntu in this same model? Could you please help me? Could you tell me the steps I have to follow?

Any help/advise will be much appreciated

**Bounty Update**

My 512 GB ssd failed to boot ubuntu installed via UEFI boot mode. my dell bios configuration looks like,

SATA: AHCI (without this setting, I cant see my ssd on ubuntu live usb)
secure boot: disabled
boot mode: UEFI

I managed to install ubuntu 16.04 via live uefi usb stick. But I can't boot from ssd. On the boot option, I tried creating a new boot menu which pointing to `efi/ubuntu/shim64x.efi` but no results. Still I'm getting the below error.

```
Product Name: Dell Inspiron 15 7000 Gaming
ePSA: UEFI ROM

No bootable devices found
```

I also tried, chroot into the installed ubuntu from live usb and changed the kernal boot parameters like below,

https://ibb.co/tzpZvsp

but still I got the same boot error "No bootable devices found". Some says SSD won't support legacy ROMs that's why I'm sticking to UEFI.

Comment: did you check the md5sums of the iso ?

Comment: Yes, I checked the md5sum

Comment: I've tried different tools to create the bootable USB: unetbootin, rufus, Universal USB Installer, ... with same results :(

Comment: You must be doing something wrong then. I mean, is a user's illiteracy issue rather than a Ubuntu's "problem".  Yes, you *may* need `nomodeset` for the gaming series that include a Nvidia graphics card but regardless of that eventual additional step, the problem boils down to how you're doing and booting the installation media. This is what you need to know: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Thanks for answering @MichaelBay, I do not think it is a illiteracy issue. I~ have tried to remove the ssd with windows, so I have my second and empty ssd on my laptop. Tried to install it also in legacy mode, and same results.

Comment: Looks like I have the same issue than this one https://askubuntu.com/questions/954706/acpi-errors-ubuntu-16-04-17-04-can-not-be-installed, but nobody has given any answer yet :(

Comment: Does yours have a Nvidia card (gaming series)? If yes, you need `nomodeset` and I hope you're setting it correctly by editing the "Try Ubuntu" entry and typing it in the same line where "quiet splash" is. Booting in Legacy is an absurd in this case and expecting better results is illogical. Even if you could boot and install in Legacy you wouldn't be able to dual boot with Grub. No need to remove the Windows drive but you must know what you're doing, i.e., where to install.

Comment: Furthermore, a quick google search (that you should have done BTW) show that you may need to upgrade the BIOS then change the SATA mode to AHCI.  https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2353195&page=2&p=13629437#post13629437 (feel free to read the whole thread but solution starts in this post),

Comment: Sorry for the late response.
@MichaelBay, I added nomodeset, acpi=off, BIOS upgraded to latest version, changed SATA mode to AHCI, disabled secure boot,... It keeps crashing after few seconds in Live mode.
I will keep trying to investigate if somebody else with same laptop has same issues, or wait until a new linux version with a new kernel solves this problem.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I just setup my Dell 7567 with dual boot for Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. My setup involves keeping windows 10 in the ssd( Tiny 128 GB version) and installing Ubuntu on the Mechanical Drive( 1 Tb). Following are the steps I followed.

1. Disable Fast Boot and Hibernate on Windows 10.
2. Advanced startup, Enter BIOS and disable Secure Boot.
3. In the BIOS there should be an option called SATA Operation Mode, 
   switch that to AHCI( DEfault is RAID). Please Note: If the setting is 
   not available on your BIOS you might need a BIOS update.
4. Setup your Ubuntu 16.04 usb boot drive using rufus. Note: Create using 
   the 'MBR partiton scheme for BIOS or UEFI Computers' option.
5. Go to advanced Start Up and boot from the created USB.
6. Once installation starts go for 'Something Else' on the installation 
   window. Make sure the grub(bootloader) is installed in the drive with 
   your Windows installation. Create your root partition and swap area in 
   the new drive(Follow Tutorials).
7. Continue with installation and try to download third party updates 
   while installing( That will solve any driver issues with the graphics 
   card)
8. Reboot and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The only difference between you and me is the second drive, yours is mechanical and mine is SSD. I think it's an hardware incompatibility issue, but I will try again replicating your steps

Comment: sorry it's not working for me.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Have you tried switching kernel? Have you read this [Dell Inspiron 7567 - Linux Kernel Support](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/dell-inspiron-7567-linux-kernel-support/7033) ?

Comment: Should be using 18.04 not older versions.  And you must update UEFI, update SSD firmware & change to AHCI all mentioned above. Similar models are essentially the same with Dell. Post installation issues Ubuntu 18.04-Dell inspiron 7559
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072382/post-installation-issues-ubuntu-18-04-dell-inspiron-7559
Dell Inspiron 7566
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2342359

Comment: @Kulfy not yet.. Currently I have 18.04 iso image . Do I need to download the ubuntu version corresponding to v4.9.111 ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj May be yes if we consider the article. Are you able to perform tasks from recovery mode without any problem? Is this problem limited to GUI mode?

Comment: ubuntu live usb stucks on language selection part but I can get into bios if necessary.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I'm not sure about your BIOS setting but I believe you are using UEFI mode. I'd suggest you to explore your BIOS setting and check all the things. I'm not sure but it may be a BIOS setting problem. I guess after language selection there is installation type and partitioning. Try checking for any errors in SSD. I do have a Dell Inspiron laptop but it isn't 7567. So, I can only assume and can't reproduce the problem

Comment: @Kulfy i managed to install 16.04 completely on my 512 GB SSD (dual boot with windows). I do see Ubuntu, Windows boot manager under the UEFI boot options but upon clicking the ubuntu option, it shows "no boot device found" error.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Do you mean no GRUB? Try Adding a new boot option (may be that one is having some problems). Or try a boot-repair from LiveUSB. If you need help how to add boot option, I've already answered a question. You can find it [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1103177/816190)

Comment: @Kulfy question updated. Tried boot repair and ran `update-grub` command on the installed ubuntu via `chroot` but nothing works

Comment: @Kulfy tried also your sol https://askubuntu.com/a/1103177/816190 ie. boot from grubx64.efi but nothing works.. Got the same "No bootable devices found err"

Comment: @Kulfy I made it to work after doing the bios update

Comment: @AvinashRaj Great!! So may be that was a BIOS problem. You might like to add that as an answer :)

Comment: seems like someone mentioned bios update in their answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is an abandoned question. The user who posted it hasn't signed on in over a year. An answer is needed for a different user who posted a bounty as such comments need to be addressed to: [Avinash Raj](https://askubuntu.com/users/202806/avinash-raj)

---

I don't have a Dell Inspiron 15 7567. But I do have a Dell Inspiron 17R 7720 SE (Ivy Bridge i7-3630QM) and a Dell Alienware 17R3 (Skylake i7-6700 HQ) with NVMe SSD. The "Dell way" is very similar with both laptops.

My AW17R3 came with a 1 TB HDD. I immediately bought a Samsung Pro 960 NVMe SSD though for greater speed. To install to the SSD I did the following:

- Remove HDD so BIOS doesn't become "confused".
- Install M.2 NVMe PCIe Gen 3.0 x 4 (bubble gum stick) SSD.
- Boot with freshly created Windows 10 Installation USB flash drive.
- Install Windows 10.
- Download and install 6 or more Dell drivers for Windows 10 and my laptop. This is very important because Windows drivers update BIOS and firmware that Linux benefits from.
- Boot with Ubuntu 16.04 Installation USB flash drive.
- Some say secure boot must be off but it works OK with it on these days.
- Some say to switch from Intel RST to AHCI but it worked OK without switching. Note for me switching to AHCI to I needed to reinstall Ubuntu but not Windows 10. However after switching to AHCI, I couldn't switch back for some reason.
- Next step was to reinstall HDD which becomes the secondary drive and SSD is now the primary boot drive.
- After installing Ubuntu 16.04 grub wouldn't boot Windows 10 until I ran `boot-repair.
- After running `boot-repair` I ended up with extra Windows boot options that didn't belong so I followed this: [Boot Repair created too many Grub menu entries for Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938633/boot-repair-created-too-many-grub-menu-entries-for-windows/1022700#1022700)

---

The error message reported in comments: *"no boot device found"* can mean many things. There are some good Youtube videos that addresses the problem:

- [Fix for Dell Error No Bootable Device Found / No Boot Device / Boot Device Not Found](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVB-tfxdQiw)
- [No Bootable Device found - After installing UBUNTU on Windows 8.1/ 10 UEFI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hi1iZThV6XA)

This video isn't as good but may help:

- [LİNUX How To Fix: No Bootable Device](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVbUrzYD8PE)

Comment: Added some updates on the original question.

Comment: after doing bios update, it works for me. Thanks..

Comment: @AvinashRaj Great news. One of the reasons I recommend users only shrink Windows down and never delete it is for applying BIOS and firmware updates.