# Accidently deleted boot option on Dell laptop

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, dell

I have a Dell laptop in which I have dual booted Ubuntu with Windows 10. Usually the laptop loads the Grub menu first.

Recently I had some problems with Windows Bitlocker: every time I open Windows I am prompted to enter the Bitlocker password. In trying to solve this, I accidentaly clicked Ubuntu in the "Delete Boot" option in the boot sequence. Now the laptop boots directly to Windows without first loading the Grub menu.

Luckily, when I restarted the system and clicked "add boot option" I found the efi folder in which the Ubuntu folder is present. In Ubuntu there is `fwgrupx64.efi`, `grubx64.efi`, `grub.cfg`, `shimx64.efi`, `mmx64.efi`, and `BOOTX64.CSV`. On clicking `grubx64.efi` it shows "Boot name not found".

How can I recover the Grub boot menu?

Comment: Thanks for the help, and quick reply, the above steps worked, did you had problems with bitlolcker?

Comment: I don't use bitlocker. I have Windows 10 Home which doesn't have Bitlocker I believe. You can ask all your Windows related questions on https://superuser.com

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No need to panic. Here is the workaround to get GRUB back.

1. Go to *BIOS settings* by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> when system boots up and Dell logo appears.
2. Go to *General→Boot Sequence*. It must look like this

   [image: BIOS setting]
3. Click on *Add Boot option*. You will get three fields: *Boot Option Name*, *File System List* and *File Name*

   [image: Boot Option fields]
4. In *Boot Option Name*, type *Ubuntu*, **Don't touch *File System List* option** and in *File Name* select the file *grubx64.efi* which must be in */EFI/Ubuntu/* and then Click on 'OK'.

   **Note**: Don't leave *Boot Option Name* empty. This will cause *Boot name not found* error.
5. This newly created boot option will appear in the end. Select that option with the mouse click and use *Arrows* beside the list to bring it on top to change boot order.

   [image: Change boot order]
6. Click on *Apply* then *Exit*
7. You must be welcomed by a familiar GRUB.

---

*These photos were clicked by mobile phone and I tried my best to get possibly best photos*.

Comment: I suspect that this will come in handy at a point in my dual boot career! Great solution!

Comment: I can't upvote this enough times! I keep coming back, mostly because I forget to type in the name.