# Problem rebooting after installing Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: boot, 18.04, system-installation

I'm experiencing some problems after finishing installation of Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 7567 with the following specs:
- SK Hynix SC311 M.2 128GB SSD with windows 10
- Toshiba HDD 1TB (where I created partitions for ubuntu during installation, via bootable usb)
- 8Gb RAM DDR4 Sk Hynix 1Rx8 2400Mhz
- Intel Core i7-7700HQ (4 physical cores) (6MB Caché, uo to 3.80 GHz)
- NVIDIA GTX 1050Ti (4Gb) GDDR5
- Only 3.0 USB ports

On the first try, I did the normal installation without changing any default setting of windows or bios. During the intallation I checked the "Download updates while installing ubuntu" option.

The installation process finished without any problem. After it was complete and after clicking on the "Restart Now" button, the problems started. Firstly, it took a while to begin the process of restarting. Then, the folowwing messages appear:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1u_l-ftis70rxAosZf0lLYNzAJ6qNc7DW

After reading some possible solutions, I did the specified on the following link: [Install Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell 15 7567](https://askubuntu.com/questions/956444/install-ubuntu-16-04-on-dell-15-7567)

In my case, since I had a previous installation, i didn't choose the "reinstall" option. I went to "something else" and overwrite the partitions that I created before. The installation went perfectly until it was completed. Again, after clicking the "restart now" button, the same issue appear.

This time, I tried to log in to Ubuntu. It showed me the Ubuntu logo but after that it was freezed. In both cases, hard shutdown was required.

What is the problem? How I can solve it?

Is a firmware bug? or a hardware problem?

Please help me, I'm starting with linux.