# Ubuntu 18.04 hangs on shutdown or restart

Tags: 18.04, shutdown

Since around one month I am having a problem with ubuntu not being able to shutdown or restart. I think this happened after some Ubuntu update but I can't figure out which was the one that caused the problem. I have already tried updating the `grub` file with: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force apm=power_off"` as I saw in some other questions here but didn't help. This is the log when it is shutting down, but it stays forever at this point:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Today after updating Ubuntu it was possible to shutdown! Most probably a new fix came along, so if anyone has same issue and none of the options suggested in the wild works, waiting a bit might be a solution before going extreme and reinstalling Ubuntu..

Comment: here's why that was happening: https://askubuntu.com/a/993734/307184 the update made this problem go away without that fix too. but maybe you should aply it anyways. Even with the update, my system behaves better on reboot and shutdown with the fix.