# Ubuntu 18.04.2 power off causes system freeze

Tags: shutdown

Ubuntu 18.04.2, the following functions cause the system to freeze. No mouse or keyboard response.

Power Down
Restart
reboot
reboot now

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://askubuntu.com/a/993734/307184

Comment: Could you give us more information please? this is very likely hardware related. we can only assume what are the issues and solutions from the little you gave us. what is the exact laptop model (long code) if it's a laptop? has this happened since day one, or did ubuntu 18.04.2 used to not have this issue for you?